# Asp.Net Core Set Default API Versioning

Tags: asp.net, .net, api, asp.net-core, versioning

I'm using Asp.Net Core as a Rest API Service. I need to have API Versioning. Actually, I set in the Startup following settings and It's work correctly but when I set to default Version It's not working on.

```
services.AddVersionedApiExplorer(
                options =>
                    {
                        options.GroupNameFormat = "'v'VVV";
                        options.SubstituteApiVersionInUrl = true;
                        options.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
                        options.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
                    });
services.AddApiVersioning(
                options =>
                    {
                        options.ReportApiVersions = true;
                        options.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
                        options.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
                    })
            .AddMvc(
                options =>
                    {
                        options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true;
                    })
            .AddXmlSerializerFormatters();
```

and set Attribute in Controllers like this:
Version 1:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
public class UsersController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("log")]
    public string Get()
    {
        return $"{DateTime.Now}";
    }
}
```

Version 2:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
[ApiVersion("2.0")]
public class UsersController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("log")]
    public string Get()
    {
        return $"{DateTime.Now}";
    }
}
```

I can get the result as fllowing urls:

http://localhost:5000/v1/users/log => Status Code: 200

http://localhost:5000/v2/users/log => Status Code: 200

But http://localhost:5000/users/log => Status Code: 404

How I can set the default API in Versioning?

Thanks, everyone for taking the time to try and help explain

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your configuration correctly sets default api version if none is specified. But your routes requires request url to include `v{version}` part. So one possible solution is to add another route without `v{version}` like this

```
[ApiController]
[Route("v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
[Route("/[controller]")]
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
public class UsersController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("log")]
    public string Get()
    {
        return $"{DateTime.Now}";
    }
}
```

Now request to `http://localhost:5000/users/log` will point to controller with api version `1.0`. If you add this route to second controller the version `1.0` will still be picked because default `ApiVersion` will be selected and it's `1.0`.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance, If I add a new route to the controller I get a new Route in Swagger Documentation.

Comment: @SaeidMirzaei My post answers the question you posted. Update it please or create separate one with the new problem. Concerning new route in swagger I don't know how to prevent this, I'm afraid you need to choose another route template for versioning, but I'm not sure.

Comment: This is the correct answer. @SaeidMirzaei, it is simply not possible to do what you're asking. You wouldn't expect `/api/values/{id}/subvalues` to work without the `{id}` parameter. The same is true when you version by URL segment. The `AssumedDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified` is not meant to address that problem and is  another example of why versioning by URL segment is the least RESTful method. Double-route registration is required. To filter OpenAPI/Swagger doc generation, you can use a custom **IApiDescriptionProvider** or **IOperationFilter** (for Swashbuckle).